# How can i appeal FORM fill up? My Adsense account is disabled

Tags: android, adsense, disable

i don't know what i place in this two fields?

FIELD: **Example URLs or app ID where you've placed your ads *** 

AND 

FIELD: **URLs or App ID where you intend to place the ads (should be active)**

in google adSense appeal [form](https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/appeal_form).

i confuse about URLs and app ID, i have google Playstore account and many application. so what can i fill in above two fields?

Answer (score 0):

URLs or app ID

I suppose these are links to your apps and can look like

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana

Comment: i have one or more apps in my google playstore account, so my all apps URLs place in these two fields? can i place like this com.facebook.katana only OR full URL ?